# Android Volley with Viewpager for news feed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-volley

I am new to android and I want to develop an app which shows image gallery by loading images in part from server(like Instagram news feed) morover I am using Volley for imageloading.I am trying to show Images in Viewpager.when user navigate through last page,I just want to add pages dynamically which shows more  images from the server(for image path I am using mySQL which respond with json objects) just like a facebook which loads posts with scroll.Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

for downloading and displaying images to a custom layout [refer here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).you can also use volley's jsonrequest to get metadata from your server